# Trim or cut audio recorded with mediarecorder JS

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, mediarecorder, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

#### Requested Knowledge

How to shorten (from the front) an array of audio blobs and still have playable audio.

#### Goal

I am ultimately trying to record a continuous 45 second loop of audio using the JS [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) API.  The user will be able to push a button and the last 45s of audio will be saved.  I can record, playback, and download a single recording just fine.

#### Issue

When I have an array called `chunks` of say 1000 blobs from the MediaRecorder and use `chunks.slice(500, 1000)` the resulting blob array can't be used to playback or download audio.

Oddly enough `chunks.slice(0,500)` still works fine.

#### Code

```
let chunks = [];

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then((stream) => {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => chunks.push(e.data);
  }

// At some later time, attempt to trim
const trimmedAudio = chunks.slice(500, 1000)
const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// audio is an audio DOM element
audio.src = audioURL;
// At this point the audio won't play
```

#### Attempted solutions

Because slicing from the beginning to the middle works, I tried reversing, slicing, and reversing back to the original direction. Failed.

I tried leaving 16 blobs at the beginning and removing some of the middle. Failed.

#### Hunch

My hunch is that the blobs don't uniformly contain data and require some conversion to [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) or a specific TypedArray.  I have tried a number of these conversions, but still have not found a solution.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated as I can find any documentation at all for editing recorded blob arrays.

## Update 2017-02-11

Based on Kaiido's advice to concatenate the chunks, convert to an ArrayBuffer, and then pass it to the web audio api, I tried the following.

```js
const blob = new Blob(chunksFromMediaRecorder, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg codecs=opus' })
// blob is Blob size: 32714, type: "audio/ogg codecs=opus"}
function playFromBlob(blob) {
  const aCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)()
  const source = aCtx.createBufferSource()
  const fileReader = new FileReader()
  let arrayBuffer
  fileReader.onload = function() {
    arrayBuffer = this.result
    console.log('arrayBuffer', arrayBuffer) // ArrayBuffer {} with byte length 32714
    aCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer) // throws: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data
      .then(decodedData => {
        // use the decoded data here
        source.buffer = decodedData
        source.connect(audioCtx.destination)
      })
  }

  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}
```

The above is successful at creating an ArrayBuffer the same size as the Blob, but when I pass it to the `decodeAudioData` function, it throws the `Unable to decode audio data` error.  Is there a step I am missing in the conversion process?

## Update 2017-02-18

Kaiido pointed out that there is a known [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642012) with chrome that would prevent me from shifting the array of audio data.  As far as I can tell this makes any sort of audio trimming or cutting **currently impossible** in chrome (Firefox the audio array trimming works, see Kaiido's comment fiddle).

In order to achieve my ultimate goal of continuous 45s of retroactive recording, I am now instantiating two `MediaRecorders` offset by 45s and swapping them out.  So when one is at 45s and the other is at 90s I start a new recording and get rid of the 90s `MediaRecorder`.  Definitely suboptimal, but the best solution I can presently find.

Comment: chunks available in `MediaRecorder.ondataavailable` event don't necessarily contain required metadata. So you can't do it on these chunks directly. You'll have to first concatenate all your chunks, then get an arrayBuffer from this. *(~following is not sure and I don't have time to check it now~)* Pass this arraybuffer to the WebAudio API, then you should be able to cut as you need and finally save it again.

Comment: Thanks Kaiido, is there a specific way to convert the concatenated blob to an ArrayBuffer that is decodable back to audio?

Comment: I guess you are using chrome here. This is [a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642012) they're working on, where recorded files from MediaRecorder are missing required metadata, thus the `decodeAudioData` method fails... Here is one [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rrqnkwk/) which *works* on FF. But anyway, since you'll have to save the shorten arrayBuffer as wav (e.g using recorder.js), or re-record it (@x1 speed) maybe you could just directly pass your stream to the WebAudioAPI instead, and use a scriptProcessorNode directly.